# User "consecutive" count - how sure are you that it's working?

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days

Yesterday I visited Stack overflow - probably two or three times. Same thing with the day before (Saturday) and I know every day last week while at work.

This morning at 8am I see "visited 253 days, 1 consecutive"

I understand that Stack Overflow time zone is not my time zone. But I don't think there could be a 24 hour period where I have not visited this site in the last 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

I don't intend this to come across as mean, but every time this is asked it reminds me of the people that call IT departments and say "the computer says my password is wrong, but there's no way I forgot it", as though maybe the computer is mistaken. Usually it's by people in the west who sign in in the evening, which is the next day GMT time, but I'm guessing if you referred to yesterday as Sunday two hours before midnight GMT, you're probably east of the line, so that makes it somewhat more unusual.

A moderator can check the access logs to see if you missed a day or not, but maybe access logs should be accessible by that user, if this keeps coming up? It might be as simple as adding a line to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to indicate if you visited the site at all that day

Comment: Usually I would agree with you, but the "consecutive" count is infamous for its weird behavior. Sometimes for example it's higher than the number of days you visited the website. So I'm skeptical.

Comment: Mean is fine and probably deserved if I'm wrong but I don't know how it could be working. I am in GMT +10 if it matters.

Comment: @Adam Well, I would expect the consecutive day code to be pretty trivial, but @Kop said it's been broken before, so maybe not. We'll have to wait for a diamond mod to check

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me. For your account, access record:

```
2010-08-16 00:16:03.543
2010-08-15 05:45:53.490
2010-08-13 00:40:07.380
2010-08-12 00:17:06.463
2010-08-11 00:01:00.220
2010-08-10 00:19:36.297
2010-08-09 00:22:00.440
2010-08-08 00:08:17.890
2010-08-07 00:49:32.410
2010-08-06 00:08:56.960
2010-08-05 00:26:37.363
2010-08-04 00:02:09.550
2010-08-03 00:07:03.653
2010-08-02 07:13:32.623
2010-08-01 10:14:11.173
2010-07-30 01:42:44.143
2010-07-29 00:27:55.293
2010-07-28 04:47:27.680
2010-07-27 05:54:11.677
2010-07-26 00:15:41.033
2010-07-25 08:23:26.330
2010-07-24 21:45:43.203
2010-07-22 01:31:35.680
2010-07-21 00:07:46.853
2010-07-20 01:27:04.290
2010-07-19 02:02:37.780
2010-07-18 21:55:54.713
2010-07-16 06:46:05.327
2010-07-15 04:24:42.537
2010-07-14 01:53:18.967
2010-07-13 00:14:04.367
2010-07-12 00:09:49.433
2010-07-11 12:11:11.787
2010-07-09 03:28:19.400
2010-07-08 22:44:19.643
2010-07-07 03:39:35.807
2010-07-06 01:17:35.103
2010-07-05 04:09:14.543
2010-07-03 09:10:47.020
2010-07-02 04:14:55.520
2010-07-01 00:07:24.163
2010-06-30 02:23:58.683
2010-06-29 06:29:33.760
2010-06-28 22:52:31.483
2010-06-27 22:51:50.987
2010-06-25 00:08:08.170
2010-06-24 05:59:48.677
2010-06-23 01:12:07.980
2010-06-22 00:07:34.723
2010-06-21 22:01:26.773
2010-06-20 23:29:47.480
2010-06-19 23:22:46.957
2010-06-18 01:12:21.267
2010-06-17 00:35:13.263
2010-06-16 01:40:36.703
2010-06-15 05:00:43.507
2010-06-14 04:02:57.843
2010-06-13 01:34:47.213
2010-06-12 01:40:45.353
2010-06-11 00:00:26.723
2010-06-10 00:44:17.417
2010-06-09 00:25:14.650
2010-06-08 00:14:39.957
2010-06-07 00:13:01.030
2010-06-06 22:59:03.853
2010-06-05 01:28:14.083
2010-06-04 00:03:28.030
2010-06-03 00:26:47.377
2010-06-02 00:36:26.000
2010-06-01 00:21:00.360
2010-05-31 00:28:35.083
2010-05-28 10:11:50.570
2010-05-22 01:35:33.247
2010-05-21 00:11:36.440
2010-05-20 01:07:24.010
2010-05-19 00:01:30.153
2010-05-18 00:09:26.300
2010-05-17 00:10:02.290
2010-05-16 22:23:59.973
2010-05-14 00:04:24.173
2010-05-13 00:07:33.507
2010-05-12 00:13:38.993
2010-05-11 01:31:31.310
2010-05-10 00:53:32.180
2010-05-07 00:00:08.017
2010-05-06 00:33:26.003
2010-05-05 00:01:52.457
2010-05-04 00:35:53.397
2010-05-03 00:05:55.853
2010-05-02 22:02:24.897
2010-04-30 00:54:24.763
2010-04-29 00:36:58.383
2010-04-28 01:23:31.603
2010-04-27 00:00:01.507
2010-04-26 22:44:09.457
2010-04-23 00:07:00.293
2010-04-22 02:09:12.093
2010-04-21 00:06:32.913
2010-04-20 04:15:06.880
2010-04-19 00:24:16.367
2010-04-18 23:15:30.900
2010-04-16 04:59:52.997
2010-04-15 01:52:50.723
2010-04-14 00:23:26.410
2010-04-13 01:32:05.167
2010-04-12 00:18:10.850
2010-04-11 21:56:57.053
2010-04-09 02:15:55.647
2010-04-08 01:33:06.527
2010-04-07 00:19:34.123
2010-04-06 00:00:54.820
2010-04-05 22:28:48.817
2010-04-01 05:41:46.683
2010-03-31 01:01:16.893
2010-03-30 00:15:28.490
2010-03-29 01:39:32.527
2010-03-28 21:28:01.693
2010-03-26 00:54:25.550
2010-03-25 00:02:30.180
2010-03-24 00:55:55.293
2010-03-23 00:14:24.537
2010-03-22 00:32:50.427
2010-03-21 22:11:01.670
2010-03-19 00:44:08.423
2010-03-18 02:24:23.867
2010-03-17 00:23:17.970
2010-03-16 00:49:28.093
2010-03-15 00:24:17.967
2010-03-14 11:23:10.977
2010-03-13 01:43:49.777
2010-03-12 00:51:08.127
2010-03-11 00:49:06.587
2010-03-10 00:41:35.370
2010-03-09 00:03:54.863
2010-03-08 03:42:43.507
2010-03-07 11:40:24.307
2010-03-06 01:35:47.127
2010-03-05 00:03:51.030
2010-03-04 00:35:03.693
2010-03-03 01:28:18.257
2010-03-02 03:00:14.267
2010-03-01 02:42:40.117
2010-02-28 00:00:05.753
2010-02-27 02:54:36.177
2010-02-26 23:51:16.533
2010-02-25 20:25:37.217
2010-02-23 01:53:38.013
2010-02-22 01:53:59.433
2010-02-21 09:46:52.927
2010-02-20 01:46:00.357
2010-02-19 02:15:54.210
2010-02-18 01:35:53.983
2010-02-17 00:49:50.340
2010-02-16 00:36:38.167
2010-02-15 00:25:06.843
2010-02-14 06:17:27.083
2010-02-13 00:34:37.833
2010-02-12 00:09:04.663
2010-02-11 00:09:02.830
2010-02-10 02:12:25.133
2010-02-09 01:41:41.787
2010-02-08 00:43:00.717
2010-02-07 01:44:00.640
2010-02-06 01:07:26.803
2010-02-05 00:30:34.147
2010-02-04 00:14:56.737
2010-02-03 00:24:31.890
2010-02-02 00:22:37.853
2010-02-01 00:41:12.423
2010-01-31 00:32:09.413
2010-01-30 01:36:34.130
2010-01-29 00:21:52.883
2010-01-28 01:18:44.727
2010-01-27 00:01:13.687
2010-01-26 05:25:14.780
2010-01-24 00:22:41.587
2010-01-23 08:13:49.800
2010-01-22 22:58:39.713
2010-01-21 08:40:52.813
2010-01-18 07:06:21.607
2010-01-17 00:31:20.037
2010-01-14 02:30:27.667
2010-01-12 06:02:35.583
2010-01-11 03:46:12.767
2010-01-10 04:09:06.877
2010-01-06 08:09:02.397
2010-01-04 21:27:27.163
2010-01-03 01:21:32.510
```

Notice 8-14 is missing.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Well if you can use cron to get it, it's probably not a must-have badge anyway :-)

Comment: But I still have a nagging feeling that there is no way 24 hours passed during visits - definitely not 27 as that log shows.

Comment: @Adam It looks like you missed three days last month anyway, so it's not a big loss (you weren't at 99 consecutive days or anything)